# If $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B)=1$, then $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B)=1$, then $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=1$?

We can use this:

$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A|B)\mathbb{P}( B)=\mathbb{P}(A|B)$

Then, we have to find counter examples for dependent events $A, B$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A|B)<1$. Are there any examples?

Comment: There are answers that provide proofs of "yes". Intuition leads to that answer too: if each of $A$ and $B$ is sure to happen (no matter what) then both are sure to happen.

Comment: @EthanBolker: [almost sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From
$$\mathbb{P} (A\cup B) = \mathbb{P} (A)+\mathbb{P} (B)-\mathbb{P} (A\cap B)$$
and $1=\mathbb{P} (A)\leq \mathbb{P} (A\cup B)\leq 1$, we get
$$
1 = 2 - \mathbb{P} (A\cap B)$$
so $\mathbb{P} (A\cap B)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A\cap B)\ge P(A)+P(B)-1=1$ since $P(A)=P(B)=1$.
Hence $P(A\cap B)=1$ since $P(A\cap B )\le1$

Comment: bah bhai bah!!!